# What is the Sourcer syntax for defining data structures?

Tags: disassemblers

I am working with version 8 circa 2000 of Sourcer from V Communications. They no longer support it. I've long since lost the manual.

There is a definition file that you edit as you discover the code you are dissembling. In that file's data section you can create a data structure using the DS command. I can't remember the syntax.

Comment: I wish I could help, I borrowed my manual to a colleague some years ago and he lost it :(

Answer (score 1):

I, too would like to see a Sourcer manual.  In partial answer, the installation contains a file SAMPLE2.DEF that contains the following text:

```
          ▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀▀
              SAMPLE2 DEFINITION FILE
          ▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄▄

 ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ Section 1: CONTROL INFORMATION   ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

uP               = 8088


 ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ Section 2: RANGE DEFINITION      ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

 ════ Segments ══════════════════════════

  begin   ....   end   ..   default  ..    seg ...  seg   
 seg:off  ..   off  ..   ds  ..   es  ...   type . size  
 -------   ...  ---- ..   ---- ----  .. ----- . -----  
none


 ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ Section 3: REFERENCE DEFINITIONS ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒

 ════ Subroutines ═══════════════════════  
  seg:off ..  type & options  ..   label     ..      comments  
  ------- ..  --------------   ..  -------------- --------------



 ════ Locations ═════════════════════════  
  seg:off ..  type & options  ..   label     ......      comments  
  ------- ..  --------------  ..   -------------- .. --------------



 ════ Data Items ════════════════════════  
  seg:off ..  type & options  ..   label     ......      comments  
  ------- ...  --------------  ..   -------------- .. --------------
```

Comment: Yes that is the generic structure of the file.  I'm looking for the specific syntax for the DS data argument that is mentioned in the SAMPLE1.DEF.

Comment: I was able to find the `SAMPLE1.DEF` [over at Textfiles](http://cd.textfiles.com/thegreatunsorted/programming/misc_programming/sample1.def). Looks like the syntax is `DS` for "data structure" but it does not list any examples of structs.

Answer (score 1):

For defining data structures use the same format like all other referances

viz `seg:off ds,<options> label,comment`

define your structure details one line per item below DS `without seg:offset`

SR normally creates a file `<infile.SDF>` with sdf extension `(sourcer default definition file)`
copy paste that file as `<infile.def>` and start modifying it to suit the needs.

```
c:\> sr foo.com (define your prefs for assembler etc here and press g)  
c:\> ren foo.sdf foo.def  
c:\> edit foo.def  

seg_a:3127   da, r 0D                  ; data_137  
seg_a:3157   da, r 55    somesymbol   ;  
seg_a:31AC   ds, r 0020  MyStruct     ;// struct defined here (Array of 0x20 structs)  
             dd, c 4     int blah     ; member 1  // need foo.rem file for comments  
             dw          short foo    ; memeber 2  
             dw          short yaa    ; member 3  
             da, r 6     pathname     ; member 4  
             dd          magic        ; member 5  
seg_a:3BB0   da, r 29                 ; data_185  

alt+f alt+ s   

c:\> sr foo.def
```

output (comments are from foo.rem file (you will have a sample file testyn.rem in your installation copy paste rename foo.rem and edit that file if you need comments)

```
C:\>grep -i -A 20 "This is mystruct" Foo.LST  

3BC5:31AC  B9F9 0008            int             dd      8B9F9h
; This is mystruct    
;  defined as    
;  typeded struct _MYSTR    
;  {    
;  ulong    
;  short    
;  short    
;  char[06]    
;  ulong    
;  }Mystr, *PMystr;
3BC5:31B0  45E8                 short           dw      45E8h
3BC5:31B2  E8F5                 short           dw      0E8F5h
3BC5:31B4  10 FC E8 C6 EC E8    pathname        db      10h, 'ⁿΦ╞∞Φ'
3BC5:31BA  DB84 B800            magic           dd      0B800DB84h
3BC5:31BE  0006 36E8            int1            dd      36E80006h
3BC5:31C2  E8F0                 short1          dw      0E8F0h
3BC5:31C4  F5A7                 short1          dw      0F5A7h
3BC5:31C6  B9 08 00             pathname1       db      '╣', 8, 0
3BC5:31C9  E8 2C F5                             db      'Φ,⌡'
3BC5:31CC  61E8 B9FA            magic1          dd      0B9FA61E8h
3BC5:31D0  0008 23E8            int2            dd      23E80008h

C:\>
```

Comment: I haven't been able to get back to this yet. I expect to be able to mark it answered in a week or so.